# Python - append data in existing table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
          00          01          02          03          04
    1  (value00)   (value01)   (value02)   (value03)   (value04)
    .      .
    .      .
    .      .
  1003 (value00)   (value01)   (value02)   (value03)   (value04)
```

I have a text file which has 5 columns, as the example above. I need to append data to this text file using Python library called Pandas. The approximately number of rows that this file, at the end, need to have is 1003. Sorry if you can't understand my explanation, I'm new at Pandas.

For example:

```
          00          01          02          03          04
1        4053        4665        1003        5823        5646
2        5656        5525        4561        4654        4568
3        4656        4652        4785        4987        2354
4        3262        2335        2154        5654        4658
5        5674        6584        4562        4568        5486
[...]   [...]       [...]       [...]       [...]       [...]
1003     3543        1351        3215        4532        1315
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @IanS I have a text file which has 5 columns, as the example above. I need to append data to this text file using Python library called Pandas. The approximately number of rows that this file, at the end, need to have is 1003. Sorry if you can't understand my explanation, I'm new at Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it using df.loc[row] which can be easily used inside loop.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(5)])
df.loc[0] = range(5) # add row 
df.loc[1] = range(5) # add row

for i in range(len(df),len(df)+2):
    df.loc[i] = range(5) # add rows to end by starting at len(df)

df
```

Returns

```
    00  01  02  03  04
0   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
1   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
2   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
3   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To add data to columns in a data frame. this will work. I think you're looking for something more programmatic. Note that all our data will need to be the same size so appending like this is tedious but it will work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'00': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
              '01': ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'],
              '02': ['value7', 'value8', 'value9'],
              '03': ['value10', 'value11', 'value12'],
              '04': ['value13', 'value14', 'value15']})

In[2]: df

Out[2]:
    00      01      02      03      04
0   value1  value4  value7  value10 value13
1   value2  value5  value8  value11 value14
2   value3  value6  value9  value12 value15
```

If they are not the same shape, you'll likely see this error `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`